# eGit Commit changed local repo but didn't push to GitHub

Tags: commit, egit

Using Eclipse/Java/MacOS with GitHub repository.  After 1.5 hours of code changes/testing to 3 code files advance 1 feature, I was doing the Team/Commit...

Inside my Commit Comment, I typed a Shift-Return to do a line feed, and the software acted as if I has pressed the dismisser (Commit & Push), clearing out the staged files list.  I kept waiting for the acknowlegement from GitHub, but it never came.

Eclipse removed all the ">" adornments (markers of dirty files which differ from the current GitHub Master branch).  If I ask to Compare a changed local file to the Master branch, it says the file is up to date, but I logged onto GitHub from another computer, and see that the Commit DID NOT happen, and the local file has many mods not in the Master.

How do I preserve the 1.5 hours of work, and get my local repo to know that these 3 files are dirty and allow them to be Committed??

And what's the deal with Eclipse going beserk inside a typed comment field?

Comment: Is there a new revision when checking `git log`?

Comment: Just in case, a _commit_ happens _locally_. So, if the revision is up on github or not _does not_ imply that the revision was not created. It might have been created and not pushed to github.

Comment: Eclipse has its own (Java-based) implementation of Git inside it, apparently. Given that your question is entirely about Eclipse behavior (rather than Git itself), shouldn't it have different tags than it does?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I noticed in the Project Resources tree on the left, the project root node, the name of the GitHub branch had a "up-arrow 1" , indicating that the local repo was one revision ahead of the remote repo.

I did a Team/Push To Origin, and it completed the botched Commit to Github.